# Android app to execute a script in background only

Tags: gratis, android, scripting

I'm searching for an Android app that can execute an script in the background. It **should not** show or change any foreground UI when the script is executed, not even a toast or notification is allowed.

**OS support**: Any Android version above 4.2.x

**Pricing**: Freeware only

**Device status**: Rooted, Xposed framework installed, though app for non-rooted devices would be nice to have

The app should allow creation of custom shortcuts for script execution which could be executed by user from home screen or by another app directly.

I suppose [Terminal Shortcut](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=de.hp.terminalshortcutdemo) can do precisely what I need but it needs to be unlocked (paid version) to get custom shortcut feature.

#### What I'm trying to achieve?

The question: [Page up and page down in web pages and elsewhere](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/56561/96277), was once asked in an another SE community. My answers there uses paid apps, a thing which may be a hindrance for some users and hence, they don't have a good alternative for my solutions.

I found that [MacroDroid](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.arlosoft.macrodroid) (an automation app) can execute an action if a hardware key such as Volume Up is pressed. All I need to do is execute a command as that action. This app doesn't provide shell commands execution like Tasker does, so that's why I'm looking for an app that can allow custom shortcut creation for execution of a script silently.

I believe [Automate](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.llamalab.automate) can be an alternative for the app I'm looking for but I don't understand its usage.